# Is there a way to call await directly in Jupyter cell?

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, jupyter-notebook, python-asyncio

I've seen examples of such code working in certain environments (eg https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/pull/323).

But for me this only raises `SyntaxError` so far:

[image]

**Update:**

I know that in "pure" python it won't work and `await` is supposed to be used in `async def`'s only.

I also know that in jupyter it *is* possible (see link above) so the engine is capable of doing this. The question is how to get rid of this error message.

**Update2**
What's the idea of calling await directly:

I'm working with an async library. In current version of jupyter it's hard to get the return value of a coroutine:

[image]
The best thing I've come up to is through global variables:

[image]

One of the problems here is that `res` is not ready in the cell 25 yet. I have to wait until I see "done", then use the value in the another cell.

Another problem is semantic asymmetry between calling a coroutine from the cell directly and from another coroutine, which is pretty irrelevant when writing scripts in an editor, but quite crucial for repl.

*Now* consider this:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Got it!

[image]

<s>This needs development version of IPython to be installed (https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/11155).</s>

Which is:

pip install git+https://github.com/minrk/ipython.git@more-await-repl#egg=ipython

pip install git+https://github.com/minrk/ipykernel.git@run-async#egg=ipykernel

**Update:**

As noted by @ack, nowadays this functionality is present in the latest version ipykernel on pypi.

Comment: This "`await` at toplevel" feature became available in IPython 7.0, and the 7.x series is now considered stable. See [this blog post](https://blog.jupyter.org/ipython-7-0-async-repl-a35ce050f7f7) for more information. If your environment doesn't have recent enough IPython version, doing `pip install ipython ipykernel --upgrade` should do the trick.

Comment: @ack Thanks! If you post this as an answer I'll accept it.