# flask python manage.py shell equivalent in fastapi

Tags: python, ipython, fastapi

I am using `python manage.py` shell in my flask application to use IPython shell for accessing my application from shell. Is there any equivalent for this in fastApi?

Answer (score 11):

If you want to interact with orm models directly, you can run `main.py` in interactive mode and import all your models there.

To enter interactive mode, run

`python3 -i app/app/main.py`

[**`-i`**](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-i) flag allows you to

> enter interactive mode after executing the script or the command

After entering the interactive shell, you can import all the models using

`from app.models import *`

Note that your models structure might be different so you have to change the above import accordingly. In my case all the models was imported in `__init__.py` file, that's why I could import all of them in one go.

Comment: But we can use async/await inside this shell, any idea how to run main.py in interactive & async mode.

Comment: You can use IPython for that. refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50844238/7699859)